# Question about differentiability and continuity for multivariate functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ be given as

$$
g(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }\text{ $x^2 + (y-1)^2 \leq 1 $ or $y \leq 0 $} \\
0, & \text{ }\text{ Otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to show that the limit

$$ T(v) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ g(0 + vt) - g(0)}{t}  \; \; \; \text{Exists $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^2$} $$

and that $T$ is linear transformation and that $g$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

### Try

We know $g(0) = 1$, then $T(v) = \lim \frac{ g(vt) - 1}{t} $. Since $g(vt)$ is either $1$ or $0$, then we see that indeed the limit exists in both cases. Is this correct? How can I show linearity of $T$?

Now, take $\mathbf{x_n} = ( - \frac{1}{n}, - \frac{1}{n}) \to (0,0) $. Notice $g( \mathbf{x_n} ) = 0 \neq 1 = g(0,0) $. Hence $g$ cannot be continuous at the origin. Can someone tell me if I am on the right track? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $g(x_n)=1$ since $-\frac{1}{n}<0$. Taking $y_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{2n^2})$ we have $||y_n-(0,1)||^2>1$ and thus $g(y_n)=0\neq 1=g(0,0)$. For the first part, we always have $T(v)=0$, see the picture:
[image]

Let $v=(a,b)$ with $b>0$. Then $g(tv)=1$ for every $t<0$ and $0\leq t<\frac{2b}{a^2+b^2}$. Now try to do the cases $b=0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you explain a little bit why $T(v) $ is awalys $0$ ?

Comment: Any doubts? Try to calculate ||tv-(0,1)||.